# Remove .php extension, force non-slash, force non-www, force https with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have been looking into this for quite a while now, but i just can't get it right. When I have one part working (e.g. forcing non-php), the other part stops working (e.g. forcing non-slash).

**What I want exactly:**

1. remove .php extension (so `example.com/foo.php` becomes `example.com/foo` in the browser url bar)
2. remove the slash at the end of a URL (so `example.com/foo.php/` becomes `example.com/foo`. BUT when it's a directory with an index.php inside, it has to redirect accordingly (i can't get this last part to work)
3. force non-www (this works)
4. force https (this works)

**What I my .htaccess looks like right now:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**I experience the following problems with this:**

1. `example.com/foo.php/` redirects to `example.com/foo.php` instead of `example.com/foo`
2. `example.com/foo.php/foo` displays the `example.com/foo.php` file, while `example.com/foo/foo` displays a 404 message (the latter would be correct in my case)
3. `example.com/admin` (this is a folder with an index.php in it) displays a 404 message

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I know it is a broad question. But if anyone ever searches for this, I almost have it (the only thing that doesn't work is redirecting `domain.com/foo.php/foo` to `domain.com/foo/foo`

Here is the .htaccess file I have right now:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^/]+)\.php(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```